# Translation invariance and finite dimension imply smoothness

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $X$ be linear subspace of $C(\mathbb R)$, the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, which is closed under translations, i.e., if $f\in X$ and $h\in\mathbb R$, then $\tau_h f\in X$, where $(\tau_h f)=f(x+h)$. If $X$ is finite dimensional, then show that $X\subset C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ - $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is the set of infinitely many times differentiable functions on $\mathbb R$. In particular, show that there exists a linear ordinary differential operator $\mathcal L=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_0$ with constant coefficients, where $n=\mathrm{dim}\,X$, such that 
$$
X=\{f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R):{\mathcal L}f=0\}.
$$

Note. If we manage to prove that $X$ is closed under differentiation, then the rest is a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton, since, if $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ is a basis of $X$, then there exist constants $c_{ij}$, $i,j=1,\ldots,n$, such that $f'_i=\sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}f_j$, and thus differentiation is transformed to multiplication by the matrix $C=(c_{ij})$, and as $p(C)=0$, where $p(\lambda)=(-1)^n\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}\cdots+a_0$ is the characteristic polynomial of $C$, then ${\mathcal L} f=0$, for every $f\in X$, where $\mathcal L=\frac{d^n}{dt^n}+a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_0$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: The question is interesting and a nice proof is given by  P. M. Anselone and J. Korevaar in the paper "Translation invariant subspaces of finite dimension", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 15 (1964), 747-752; see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-05/S0002-9939-1964-0169048-7/

Comment: possible duplicate of [A question about the vector space spanned by shifts of a given function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302369/a-question-about-the-vector-space-spanned-by-shifts-of-a-given-function)